# Detecting Super Dev Mode from within GWT app

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I guess the title says it all:

Is there some kind of flag that allows my GWT app to check whether it is currently running in Super Dev Mode (something along the lines of [`GWT.isProdMode()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#isProdMode()), maybe)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/7631) about having a public accessor like `GWT.isProdMode()`.

In the mean time, if you *really* need to know, there's a deferred binding property named `superdevmode` that you can use in your `<replace-with>` or `<generate-with>` rules.

Comment: I would use `<when-property-is name="superdevmode" value="on" />` for this, correct?

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As it was already mentioned, there is a `superdevmode` property that you can use.

Here is a real-life example:

1. Create a class containing a method that tells that we **are not** in SuperDevMode:

   ```
   public class SuperDevModeIndicator {
       public boolean isSuperDevMode() {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Extend previous class and override a method to tell that we **are** in SuperDevMode:

   ```
   public class SuperDevModeIndicatorTrue extends SuperDevModeIndicator {
       @Override
       public boolean isSuperDevMode() {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use only one, appropriate class depending on a `superdevmode` property - use deferred binding - put this in your `*.gwt.xml`:

   ```
   <!-- deferred binding for Super Dev Mode indicator -->
   <replace-with class="com.adam.project.client.SuperDevModeIndicatorTrue">
     <when-type-is class="com.adam.project.client.SuperDevModeIndicator"/>
     <when-property-is name="superdevmode" value="on" />
   </replace-with>
   ```
4. Instantiate `SuperDevModeIndicator` class via deferred binding:

   ```
   SuperDevModeIndicator superDevModeIndicator = GWT.create(SuperDevModeIndicator.class);
   ```
5. Use it to check whether you are in SuperDevMode or not:

   ```
   superDevModeIndicator.isSuperDevMode();
   ```

Voila!

Here you will find documentation on [Deferred binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html).

Comment: Could you use this technique in some variation on server? I can use GWT.create() only on client

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is an "official" way, but this should work:

```
Storage stockStore = Storage.getSessionStorageIfSupported();
if (stockStore != null)
{
    boolean isSuperDevMode = stockStore.getItem("__gwtDevModeHook:" + GWT.getModuleName()) != null);
}
```

Comment: :) Clever hack! I like it. But I think I'll go with the deferred binding approach suggested by @ThomasBroyer, especially since (I think) this can be used with code elimination in libraries that I use outside GWT as well. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use **GWTHelper.isSuperDevMode()** method implemented below.

```
public final class GWTHelper {

    public static boolean isSuperDevMode() {
        final Storage storage = Storage.getSessionStorageIfSupported();
        if (storage == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final String devModeKey = "__gwtDevModeHook:" + GWT.getModuleName();
        return storage.getItem(devModeKey) != null;
    }

}
```

Source : https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/core/linker/DevModeRedirectHook.js

Answer (score 0):

To check for dev app server:
GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()    returns  http://127.0.0.1:8888/

Server side: request.getRemoteHost()
should return the same (though I haven't tested this).

To check for Super Dev Mode (vs dev app server without SDM):
If GWT.getModuleBaseURL() & GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles() differ,
you're in Super Dev Mode.

property name="superdevmode" solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used following method:

`private static native boolean isSuperDevMode()/*-{
   return typeof $wnd.__gwt_sdm !== 'undefined';
 }-*/;`

Works in GWT 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles().contains("9876")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good solution.

```
boolean superdevmode = "on".equals(System.getProperty("superdevmode"));
```

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest:

```
public boolean isSuperDevMode()
{
    return Window.Location.getPort().equals("8888");
}
```

Comment: dev mode can be launched not only for localhost